# ITelephony.aidl not working

Tags: android, aidl

I don't understand how ITelephony.aidl needs to be defined or used.

For example, setting it as ITelephony.aidl under the following path:

[image]

gives me an error in the following code:

```
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    Method m = null;
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
        m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    m.setAccessible(true);
    ITelephony telephonyService;
```

The complaint is that cannot resolve symbol 'ITelephony'

However, renaming the ITelephony.aidl to Itelephonyjava seems to resolve compilation errors, but doesn't actually provide the necessary functionality.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

For every `*.aidl` file there is a corresponding `*.java` file created under

> {project path}/ build/ generated

Follow these steps:

1. Clear `/generated` folder for your project
2. Clean your code in Android Studio
3. Run (even if Studio shows you error Message, but make sure your .aidl file has correct import statement)

Hope it helps . !!